# Access the ref in a ConsumerStatefulWidget in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a ConsumerStatefulWidget and a ConsumerState class. I want to access my StateNotifierProvider inside the ConsumerState class but I am getting an error on ref saying **The instance member 'ref' can't be accessed in an initializer**.

I have been working on this for quite a while and I am learning a lot but I thought I could access ref inside the ConsumerState class.

Here is my code:

```
// Create the global provider
final globalProvider = StateNotifierProvider<GlobalsNotifier, Globals>(
    (ref) => GlobalsNotifier(Globals(
        currentUid: '',
        currentUEmail: '',
        userDocumentId: '',
        companyId: '',
        mlsId: '',
        currentTrxnId: '',
        currentCompanyName: '',
        currentCompanyState: '',
        currentUserId: '',
        currentUserName: '',
        currentUserState: '',
        selectedCompany: '',
        selectedState: '',
        selectedTrxnState: '',
        selectedUser: '',
        selectedUserState: '',
        targetScreen: '',
        newCompany: true,
        newEvent: true,
        newTrxn: true,
        newUser: true)));

class LoginScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'login_screen';

  @override
  ConsumerState<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends ConsumerState<LoginScreen> {
  bool showSpinner = false;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final globals = ref.read(globalProvider);  <<<< Access ref here

  late String email;
  late String password;

  getCurrentAgencyName() async {
    final DocumentSnapshot _currentAgentProfile =
        await agentsRef.doc(ref.watch(globalProvider.currentUid)).get();

    if (_currentAgentProfile != null) {
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.companyId.notifier).state =
          _currentAgentProfile.get('agencyId');
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserStateProvider.notifier).state =
          _currentAgentProfile.get('state');
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.mlsId.notifier).state =
          _currentAgentProfile.get('mlsId');
    }

    final DocumentSnapshot _currentAgencyProfile =
        await agencyRef.doc(ref.watch(GlobalsProvider.companyId)).get();

    if (_currentAgencyProfile != null) {
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentCompanyState.notifier).state =
          _currentAgencyProfile.get('state');
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentCompanyName.notifier).state =
          _currentAgencyProfile.get('name');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool loginFail = false;
    String errorMessage = "";

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          // children: [
          //   Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',
          //       fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 56),
          // ],
        ),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // This fixes the keyboard white space
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'Login',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  fontSize: 40.0,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 48.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  email = value;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Email',
                  errorText: loginFail ? 'incorrect email' : null,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  password = value;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  errorText: loginFail ? 'incorrect passwowrd' : null,
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ResetPasswordScreen())),
              ),
              TextButton(
                  child: const Text(
                    'Forgot Password',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = true;
                    });
                    try {
                      UserCredential userCredential =
                          await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: email, password: password);

                      if (userCredential != null) {
                        // Set the global state
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUid.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserId.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUEmail.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.email;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.targetScreen.notifier).state =
                            0;
                        await getCurrentAgencyName();
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()),
                        );
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          loginFail = true;
                        });
                      }
                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = false;
                      });
                    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                      switch (error.code) {
                        case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                        case "invalid-email":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
                          break;
                        case "email-already-in-use":
                          errorMessage = "Email is already in use.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                        case "wrong-password":
                          errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                        case "user-not-found":
                          errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
                        case "user-disabled":
                          errorMessage =
                              "User with this email has been disabled.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
                        case "too-many-requests":
                          errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
                        case "operation-not-allowed":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
                          break;
                        default:
                          errorMessage =
                              "An undefined Error happened. Please try again.";
                      }

                      if (errorMessage != null && errorMessage != "") {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            (SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage))));
                      }
                    }
                  }),
              RoundedButton(
                  title: 'Log In',
                  colour: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = true;
                    });
                    try {
                      UserCredential userCredential =
                          await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: email, password: password);

                      if (userCredential != null) {
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUid.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserId.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUEmail.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.email;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.targetScreen.notifier).state =
                            0;
                        await getCurrentAgencyName();
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()),
                        );
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          loginFail = true;
                        });
                      }
                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = false;
                      });
                    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                      switch (error.code) {
                        case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                        case "invalid-email":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
                          break;
                        case "email-already-in-use":
                          errorMessage = "Email is already in use.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                        case "wrong-password":
                          errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                        case "user-not-found":
                          errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
                        case "user-disabled":
                          errorMessage =
                              "User with this email has been disabled.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
                        case "too-many-requests":
                          errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
                        case "operation-not-allowed":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
                          break;
                        default:
                          errorMessage =
                              "An undefined Error happened. Please try again.";
                      }

                      if (errorMessage != null && errorMessage != "") {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            (SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage))));
                      }
                    }
                  }),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 100.0,
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text(
                  'New User?  Create Account',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => UserRegisterScreen())),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Am I using the correct class or should I be using something else in place of the StatefulWidget class?

I am obviously not referencing ref in the correct place so where should I access it so I can use it throughout the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ref` is a property of ConsumerState (and its subclasses).  As a property, you cannot use it in the initializer of another property, similar to the way that:

```
int f = 5;
int g = f + 2; // not allowed
```

is not allowed.  All initializers are presumed to execute "in a silo", not seeing any neighboring values.

The proper response is to declare the property as `late`, and initialize it in an overridden `initState`, where the remaining properties will be available to use.